# How can I tell if this is hardwood or subfloor?

Tags: hardwood-floor, hardwood, hardwood-refinishing

[image: Photo of the carpet, pad, and wood taken from lifting up the carpet from the vent cover.]

[image: Photo of an unfinished closet that leads to the crawlspace.]

Photo 1: Photo of the carpet, pad, and wood taken from lifting up the carpet from the vent cover.

Photo 2: Photo of an unfinished closet that leads to the crawlspace.

Would a vent ever be installed on top of hardwood or is this definitely subfloor?

Comment: That looks likes plywood, which is usually used as sub floor.  Plywood is basically thin wood glue on a base and can be a hardwood.  Hardwood floors are usually about 3/4 inch thick real wood, usually in thin(4 or 6 inch) strips.  Not saying that a bit of sanding, some stain and a clear cover coat it will look almost like a hardwood floor.  Plywood is usually in 4x8 sheets.

Answer (score 3):

That’s plywood subfloor. Definitely not hardwood.

Source: experience.

Comment: Rotary veneer grain patterns are something of a dead giveaway that falls under "experience."

Comment: Also the surface splinters and the fact that it’s a huge sheet at least a couple feed in each direction, not limited to a couple inches in width.

Answer (score 0):

That is clearly plywood subfloor.

See the big nails they used to nail it on.

You would not do that with hardwood floor.